# I need help i have face problem attribute 'android:name' in <activity> tag must be a valid Java class name

Tags: react-native

C:\Users\TEHSEEN AFZAL\AppData\yes\rn-course\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:24: AAPT: error: attribute 'android:name' in  tag must be a valid Java class name.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

[image]
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
11 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 9 up-to-date
error Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
[image]

Comment: It's easier to find issue if you share the `...debug\AndroidManifest.xml` file content

Comment: Code is given below

Comment: Hi @TehseenAfzal. You should have edited your original post to add the code example, instead of submitting it as an answer. As for your question, it doesn't look like (rncourse) is a valid app name. can you try removing the parentheses around rncourse? This should resolve the issue. However if you're having a hard time doing this manually, try https://github.com/junedomingo/react-native-rename

Comment: Thanks a lot finally it resolves after removing the parentheses around rncourse

Answer (score 0):

In my case I've removed **com.rncourse** from **android:name** both the application and activity tag and it works like a charm!

So, try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.rncourse"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="28" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:name=".MainApplication"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:appComponentFactory="android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Yes now it working by emoving the parentheses around rncourse

Answer (score -1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.(rncourse)"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="28" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:name="com.(rncourse).MainApplication"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:appComponentFactory="android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.(rncourse).MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: `package="com.(rncourse)"` is the same as `package="com.rncourse"`